# guzzle http unable to upload file to box

Tags: php, jwt, box, guzzle

I am trying to upload file using the code below

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => "Bearer {$access_token}",
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ], 
    'attributes' => [
        'name' => $file,
        'parent' => ['id',$parent_id],
        'file' => $filePath
    ]
]);
```

After I run the code on browser, I get this below error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: POST https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content resulted in a 415 Unsupported Media Type

Any better approach to upload file using GuzzleHttp?.

Comment: The error _"Unsupported Media Type"_ doesn't sound like a Guzzle issue. It sounds like you're trying to upload something the API doesn't support. Check [this page](https://community.box.com/t5/Developer-Troubleshooting/API-Content-quot-415-unsupported-media-type-quot/ta-p/64665) out and see if it helps.

Comment: This https://developer.box.com/docs/error-codes#section-415-unsupported-media-type may be of help.

Comment: agreed. The file i am uploading is just a PDF. dO YOU SEE ANY mistakes in the code pasted above?